# How do I find the marginal distributions of a GARCH(p, q) process?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, autocorrelation, autoregressive, garch

Let $X_t$ be a stationary GARCH(p, q) process. Given the coefficients for the process, how do I derive the stationary/marginal distribution? What about the distribution after only marginalizing out some of the variables? I'd like to do Bayesian estimation of a GARCH process under the assumption that the first few observations are drawn from the stationary distribution.

Comment: I have a hunch that an analytical expression would be hard/impossible to obtain except perhaps for very simple cases like ARCH(1) with normal standardized innovations.

Comment: Assuming normal innovations is fine (that's what I had in mind). Analytical expressions aren't necessary, so long as the procedure is tractable, e.g. "The roots of such-and-such polynomial."  (By tractable, I mean it can't cause trouble by being way too slow inside HMC, so it can't be "simulate a GARCH process with those parameters and then calculate the covariance.")